# Android Floating Action Button animation

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, floating-action-button

All I want is a simple animation, when the scrollview moves. I have tried some solution, but none of them worked perfectly/smoothly.If I scroll, I want to hide the fab with slide down animation and if nothing happens after 2 sec the fab shows with slide up animation. I know it is a basic question and I appreciate your patientence.

Thanks in advance.

```
final ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.sw);
scroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, Motionevent event){
      int action = event.getAction();
      if (action == Motionevent.ACTION_MOVE){

      //slide down animation here

      }else{
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){

          //slide up animation here

          }
        }, 2000);
      }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's [a tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons) , how to use the FAB button with scroll animation.

Basically:

1. Use the v22.2.1 support v4 library, there is a `show()` and `hide()` method that performs the fade-in and fade-out animations for Floating Action Buttons
2. You must place your `ScrollView` and the FAB inside a CoordinatorLayout.
3. Set the FAB `layout_anchor` to the `ScrollView's` `id`
4. Create a class and extend the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` class and set it to the FAB's `layout_behavior` attribute in the layout xml
5. Override your Behavior class `onStartNestedScroll` to check the is vertical
6. Override your Behavior class `onStopNestedScroll` to call the child's(FAB) parameter `hide()` method on downscroll and postDelay a `Runnable` to show the FAB after 2 seconds

layout like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
... >
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myList"
    ...
    />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/myList"
        app:layout_behavior="package.CustomScrollAwareBehavior"
        ...
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I suggest, to also create a `Handler` into the Behavior class to call the FAB's `show()` method.
Behavior class like (not tested):

```
public class CustomScrollAwareBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior{

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private FloatingActionButton fab;

public CustomScrollAwareBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                   FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    fab = child;
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL ||
            super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target,
                    nestedScrollAxes);
}



Runnable showRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fab.show();
    }
};


@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child,
                           View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
            dyUnconsumed);
     if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(showRunnable);
        handler.postDelayed(showRunnable,2000);
        child.hide();
    } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Pretty accurate answer, i will try this solution asap.